# Learning Django Unit test of a Jsonresponse POST

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I've written a **view** to handle post and get request:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, request
import json

def Dati(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    dati = externalfunction()
    return JsonResponse(dati)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    data = json.loads(request.POST['json'])
    for item in data:
         print " POST DA clIENT:", item, data[item]

    # FEEDBACK 
    resp = {"ok":"ricevuto"}
    return JsonResponse(resp)
```

here is the **test.py**

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from myapp.views import Dati

class ComPageTest(TestCase):

def test_url_resolves_to_vista_Dati(self):
    found = resolve('/mixd/') 
    self.assertEqual(found.func, Dati) 

def test_Dati_GET(self):
    client = APIClient()
    response = client.get('/mixd/')   
    self.assertIn(b'power', response.content)

def test_Dati_POST(self):
    client = APIClient()
    response = client.post('/mixd/', {'power': 'on'}, format='json')
    self.assertIn(b'ok', response.content)
```

the GET test run fine, the POST return this error:

```
    2015-08-09 10:32:49,131 - ERROR - Internal Server Error: /mixd/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/.virtualenvs/venvv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
/datastructures.py", line 322, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "'json'"
*** MultiValueDictKeyError: "'json'"
```

if I access the page manually everything seems fine POST seems to work. 
is there some special syntax to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `post data` is seem as

```
{'power': 'on'}
```

Then `request.POST['json']` will get `MultiValueDictKeyError: "'json'"` ?.Try

```
client.post('/mixd/', json.dumps({'power': 'on'}),
                                content_type="application/json")
```

And then change

```
data = json.loads(request.POST['json'])
```

to

```
data = json.loads(request.body)   #request.raw_post_data on Django < 1.4)
```